# What is the Microsoft SQL Server equivalent to Postgres Function DATE_PART?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query in PostgreSQL which looks like this:

```
DATE_PART('day', to_timestamp(campo3, 'DD MM YYYY')::timestamp  - to_timestamp(campo13, 'DD MM YYYY')::timestamp ) AS IMPORTO
```

How can I convert this to run in Microsoft SQL Server?

Currently, I get a syntax error at the `::` part.

Comment: Um... that is "in SQL language"... Do you mean you want to convert it to run on some other DB system, like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?

Comment: your qry should give you difference in days - what's the problem?

Comment: This not works in microsoft Sql give me a error for ::

Comment: OK, I've [edit]ed your question. "SQL" is the language which both Postgres and Microsoft SQL Server use; "SQL Server" would have been clear enough, but "Microsoft SQL Server" avoids all confusion. However, it feels like you're not breaking down the problem very well - you asked about `DATE_PART`, but are actually stuck on `::` (which is just Postgres-specific syntax for `CAST()`). Take a step back, and look up "date functions sql server" in your favourite search engine; maybe you can find something there.

Comment: add expected result with example, it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can try (substitute the date with your field name):
For testing:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,  CONVERT( datetime, REPLACE('23 02 2017',' ','/') ,103 )
    ,  CONVERT( datetime, REPLACE('23 04 2017',' ','/') ,103 ) ) AS X
```

Change with field name:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,  CONVERT( datetime, REPLACE(field1namehere,' ','/') ,103 )
    ,  CONVERT( datetime, REPLACE(field2namehere,' ','/') ,103 ) ) AS X
```

Comment: My field is a String not date :-( when i try send me this error) The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: You should replace only  '23 02 2017'` with your field name

Comment: i try it but my field provenience contain a Data time setting 01/01/1970 01:01 but is setting string field

Comment: ...adding LEFT( fieldname, 8)?  Think about the importance (next time you post a question) to add SAMPLE DATA (script for insert)

Comment: you can write all expression? i love you :)

Comment: "I love you" is a bit too much... Try to insert LEFT or SUBSTRING by yourself... and then ask me again.  E' un buon esercizio e non dovrebbe essere difficile